# reading values from excel file using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, java-io

[image: Excel file]

Hello everyone,

I want to read the values of documents i shown in an image.
currently, i am using switch-case statement to save the data, but it is very hard to differentiate from `1. Contact` to `2. Contact`.

```
case "Address Line"
     contact1.setAddressLine(cellIterator.next().getStringCellValue());
case "City"
     contact1.setCity(cellIterator.next().getStringCellValue());
case "County"
     contact1.setCounty(cellIterator.next().getStringCellValue());
...and so on for Address
case "Number of Students"
     contact1.setAddressLine(cellIterator.next().getStringCellValue());
case "Number Of Professors"
     contact1.setAddressLine(cellIterator.next().getStringCellValue());
```

This works for `University` and `Professors` but not for `Contact`.

Can anyone guide me how can i do this?

(Sub question: Is it possible to read all values and store it which is not fixed to particular structure ?)

Answer (score 1):

If the structure of the excel file is static you can refer to the values using their coordinates instead of using a cellIterator.

A cell A1 can be referenced as

```
Sheet sheet = ...
Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
Cell cell = row.getCell(0);

// Do what you need
```

So if for example address of contact one is on B5 and address of contact two is in E5

```
Sheet sheet = ...
Row row = sheet.getRow(4);           // Reference to row 5
Cell cellContact1 = row.getCell(1);  // Reference to cell B5

Cell cellContact2 = row.getCell(4);  // Reference to cell E5
```

**Note:**

Use `getRow` and `getCell` in an existing excel to read values

Use `createRow` and `createCell` in a new excel to create values